# Bank Account table design

Tags: sql, database-design

I am writing a small simple bank account manager for myself and my wife, and maybe, if it's good, release it a bit more.

But for now, I am on the bank account design for the database.

At the moment, I have a table to hold bank accounts, which has the type, minimum balance etc. I also have a transaction table, with an account id, so on this account, I paid $50 to this third party. Or, I received $100 from this party.

But now, inter account transfers - I want to transfer $20 to my credit card, which is another account. The simple answer is just have a debit in the sending account, and a credit in the receiving account. But, I am thinking maybe it's better to have the account_transaction table hold payments and receipts from 3rd parties, and create an inter-account-transfer table. And all that has is 'sending_account_id, receiving_account_id and amount' plus all the audit type fields.

The benefit is referential integrity. Only one amount is typed in, and the table makes sure that there is a valid from, and to account. The only issue is that when I display a list of transactions, I need to select from two tables and do a union or something....

Would this new table be good design, or just stick to a transaction table, and have a nullable 'other_account_id' and set that when transaction type is 'inter account transfer'?

Comment: You must have a very tolerant wife

Answer (score 1):

IMO keep it simple, without any "special rules" for some kind of transactions. Inter account transfer is transfer like any other, so save it like other transfers in account_transaction. Later you can specially mark them on a report examining whether the both accounts belong to you.